# Wifi connected but no ping (narrowed down to Ethernet interface somehow interfering with Wifi functionality)

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, ping

I've recently been getting into Linux (Debian - Gnome shell) and am currently having trouble with my WiFi.

Basically when I reboot the WiFi works fine for about a minute or two, after that it remains connected but I can't ping any external IP (8.8.8.8 is my test IP address). After googling similar issues I tried a few of the tools I saw suggested.

running `route -n` on boot (when WiFi is working) gives the following:

```
Destination    gateway        Genmask       Flags  Metric Ref Use Iface
0.0.0.0        192.168.178.1  0.0.0.0       UG     1024   0   0   wlan0
169.254.0.0    0.0.0.0        255.255.0.0   U      1000   0   0   wlan0
192.168.178.0  0.0.0.0        255.255.255.0 U      0      0   0   wlan0
```

After a minute or so when the internet access cuts out if I run the same command I get:

```
Destination    gateway        Genmask       Flags  Metric Ref Use Iface
0.0.0.0        0.0.0.0        0.0.0.0       U      1002   0   0   eth0
0.0.0.0        192.168.178.1  0.0.0.0       UG     1024   0   0   wlan0
169.254.0.0    0.0.0.0        255.255.0.0   U      0      0   0   eth0
169.254.0.0    0.0.0.0        255.255.0.0   U      1000   0   0   wlan0
192.168.178.0  0.0.0.0        255.255.255.0 U      0      0   0   wlan0
```

so I tried shutting down `eth0` with: `ifconfig eth0 down` and voila the internet works again. for another minute or so only for `eth0` to somehow come back online and mess it up again.

I really have no idea what's going on being so new to Linux, so if anyone could shed some light on why `eth0` keeps coming online and clashing with my WiFi would be appreciated.

**---- EDIT ----- Found the ACTUAL solution for gnome-shell**

So all of the solutions I found on the suggested threads (and supposedly duplicate questions) didn't actually help me in the long run. Or they were sub-optimal solutions that forced annoying manual reconfiguration of network devices every time devices are changed.

what I ended up doing was simply removing the eth0 interface from `/etc/network/interfaces`

so by commenting the following:

`# allow-hotplug eth0
 # iface eth0 inet dhcp`

This allows the network manager that comes with Gnome to take control of eth0 and stops the clashing of the interfaces. meaning the standard GUI networking tools acted as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to permanently disable eth0 from your system, i suggest you to edit the network configuration interfaces:

```
sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

Then add the line:

```
iface eth0 inet manual
```

Once you modified the file, you can restart the network manager by invoking the command:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Of course, the mod is reversible.

If you want to mess around with interface metrics to assign priority to an interface above another, i suggest you to try `ifmetric`.

Comment: ethernet always has precedence over wifi by default in Linux.

Comment: but why does it appear and clash when it isn't plugged in?

Comment: This forces manual configuration if ethernet is wanted again. See edit in my original post.